# Substitution for DELETE INNER JOIN in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, subquery

I have some SQL Server queries that I need to convert into SQL Server CE. I am facing some troubles to say the least. This is what I am working with:

```
DELETE FROM exSetData 
WHERE exSetData 
INNER JOIN Exercise ON exSetData.exName = Exercise.Name 
WHERE Exercise.Day = @name;
```

I began by attempting to use `AND EXISTS` in SQL Server CE, however I do not believe it is capable of performing the task I need and clearly I am using it incorrectly.

```
DELETE FROM exSetData 
WHERE EXISTS (Exercise.Name = exSetData.exName AND Exercise.Day = @name)
```

Syntax error.

How might one do this same query in SQL Server CE?

Are there any other commands you would advise me to look into? I have been using Microsoft documentation however it is not as thorough in `DELETE` (in my opinion).

I'm using SQL Server CE 4.0 by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work using `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM exSetData
WHERE exName IN (
    SELECT Name
    FROM Exercise
    WHERE Day = @name )
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c40a/1)

While I can't test in CE, I think your original join syntax is off and should look like this:

```
DELETE a
FROM exSetData a
  JOIN exercise e on a.exName = e.Name
WHERE e.Day = @name
```

Comment: @40Alpha -- np, glad I could help.  What error are you getting and with which query?

Comment: I was making multiple queries in one command. (Using C# VS12) For example: sqlCeCommand foo = new sqlCeCommand(query1;query2;query3;). I could do this with a normal sqlCommand however it seems not to like it in SQLCE so I made 3 different calls.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax for EXISTS:

```
DELETE FROM exSetData 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
       SELECT * FROM Exercise 
       WHERE Exercise.Name = exSetData.exName 
       AND Exercise.Day = @name
)
```